# How to return unique rows within a column in Android SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite

Really all I want to do is say the query `SELECT DISTINCT column FROM table` but I can't figure out how to structure it in the enourmous query methods that are part of `SQLiteDatabase`

I'm just trying to get the names of all contacts in a table.

Comment: Are you having trouble with the SQL statement or with the API?

Comment: The API. I believe the statement I want is SELECT DISTINCT column FROM table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to know the sql query you want to run. Have you tried using [rawQuery()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)?

Comment: This is exactly it; I've tested it and it works how I want it. Are there any advantages to "query" over "rawQuery" as Ted Hopp suggested I use.

Comment: Sorry I do not know if there is any advantage to using query over rawQuery. However I would recommend using rawQuery if you know SQL because it's easier to read and you don't to memorize the order of the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably find [this version of the SQLiteDatabase#query](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method most useful.

Comment: This is actually what's giving me problems. @f20k might have what I need.